# Link outside of Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I testing my React App and I have an error of all Link react router dom in my views.

**Index.js**

```
import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Switch,
 Route
} from "react-router-dom";

function App({props}) {
 return (
  <div>
   <Navbar />
     <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Homepage} appProps={props}/>
      <Route path="/accueil" exact component={Homepage} appProps={props}/>
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
   <Footer />
  </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <App />
 </Router>,
 document.getElementById("fatboar")
);
```

**Homepage.js**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Homepage(props) {
  return ( 
   <Link to="/ajouter-ticket" className="primary-btn mt-5">Je participe</Link>
  )
}
```

How my Link is outside of my router ?

Comment: How are you rendering the component you are "testing" that is causing the error? When you say "Test", do you mean an *actual* unit test, or you are simply testing some UI out in a browser?

Comment: Yes when you testing a React Router Dom, a page with only a Link. He doesn't run the context. Then I need to give him a Router in the test for be good. It's ok, I found the solution ;) thx for reply

Comment: Right, when testing components that are normally rendered within a `Router` in the app you need to provide or wrap it in the unit test(s) as well (same for any other providers, like redux, theme, etc...). IDK what testing framework you are using, but react-testing-library is great for this. It is easy to create your own mock HOC wrappers collection (even composable just like the real app's HOC's) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The **Link** is navigate to **/ajouter-ticket** and as I see from your code you never put a Route to this Link due to this you navigate to the Error Component
and if you read the react-router-dom doc
you will see that when you navigate to something that doesn't define in the Switch Route go to the Route Without a path
[React Router Dom Doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

```
<Route path="/ajouter-ticket" exact component={SomeComponent} appProps={props}/>
```

also, why do you have to routes to the HomePage?

Comment: The issue isn't that a path doesn't exist, as you correctly point out that `to="/ajouter-ticket"` will match the error route. OP says issue is the `Link` on the `Homepage` isn't rendered within a `Router`.

Comment: It's tottally different. It's a Link in the Homepage, not a router. Then when I render in Test the Homepage, he doesn't understand the context. Then I need to put the Router in the test for run correctly. Thx for reply